# splitting by white space or multiple white spaces

Tags: jquery

Right now I split words by one whitespace and store in an array: `var keywds = $("#searchquery").text().split(" ");`

The problem is there can/might be multiple white spaces. For example :

```
"hello      world"
```

How would I still have the array = `[hello, world]`

Comment: The problem is there can/might be multiple white spaces. For example : "hello world" .... I see only one whitespace

Comment: He's added many but SO is rendering with just one :)

Comment: ahh typo in the question

Comment: Cheap and nasty method is to replace all double spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use a regular expression (`\s` matches spaces, tabs, new lines, etc.)

```
$("#searchquery").text().split(/\s+/);
```

or if you want to split on spaces only:

```
 $("#searchquery").text().split(/ +/);
```

`+` means *match one or more of the preceding symbol*.

**Further reading:**

- [MDN - `string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [MDN - Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: whats the difference between the two expressions specifically

Comment: @Praneet: As I wrote, `\s` matches spaces, tabs, new lines, etc ...  a space only matches a space ;)